# Referencing a method from an instantiated class, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, appkit

In a game I'm working on for OSX 10.4.11, I have an NSObject that has been instantiated and functions as a controller for a couple of NSWindows. One of these windows has an NSView in it. The NSView's controller needs to call a method in the NSObject controlling the window it is running in. However, the method is not static. How do I go around calling it?

Comment: Typically you'd pass the window controller down to the view controller when you instantiate the view controller. How do you instantiate the view controller?

Comment: This is Xcode 2.5, it predates nsviewcontroller. The windows are handled by an nsobject that has been linked to the nib file. The nsobject is unsubstantiated inside the interface builder. As for why I am using tiger, my laptop died and its the only computer I have for the next month or so.